# What does "Three points" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *Fight Club (1999)*, two technicians lead Narrator to the burnt out shell of a
Wrecked automobile.  Narrator sets down his briefcase, opens it
and starts to make notes on a clipboarded form.

> Narrator: I was a recall coordinator. My job was to apply the
> formula.
>
> Technician #1: The infant went through the windshield. **Three points**.
>
> Narrator: A new car built by my company leaves somewhere traveling  at
> 60mph.

What does "Three points" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's presumably a part of the aforementioned formula - for example, the formula might go something like:

> (passenger safety) + (damage to car) + (damage to cargo) + ...

and the scoring sheet says:

> Passenger goes through the windshield - 3 points
>
> ...
>
> Passenger stays in their seat - 10 points

So the technician makes a note of what happened, and assigns a point value which is then used to calculate an overall score, based on which the car will either be recalled or not.